# How to subset EURO-CORDEX model output (rotated lat lon projection) in python?

Tags: python-xarray, projection

I have to process the REMO2015 output and am struggling with the dimensions rlat, rlon given that it has a rotated lat lon projection. I need to subset/slice the data for different regions.
Here is the script I have. Any help on how to deal with rotated lat lon systems to slice the data.
Many thanks.

```
import xarray as xr

#Sample file of the REMO2015 files
ds=xr.open_dataset("/home/remo_temp_sample.nc")

#quick look at the ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                     (time: 1826, bnds: 2, rlat: 412, rlon: 424,
                                 vertices: 4)
Coordinates:
  * time                        (time) datetime64[ns] 2006-01-01T12:00:00 ......
  * rlat                        (rlat) float64 -23.38 -23.27 ... 21.72 21.84
  * rlon                        (rlon) float64 -28.38 -28.27 ... 18.04 18.16
    lat                         (rlat, rlon) float32 ...
    lon                         (rlat, rlon) float32 ...
    height                      float64 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds, vertices
Data variables:
    time_bnds                   (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] ...
    rotated_latitude_longitude  int32 ...
    lat_vertices                (rlat, rlon, vertices) float32 ...
    lon_vertices                (rlat, rlon, vertices) float32 ...
    tasmax                      (time, rlat, rlon) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/34)
    institution:                    Helmholtz-Zentrum Geesthacht, Climate Ser...
    institute_id:                   GERICS
    experiment_id:                  rcp26
    source:                         GERICS-REMO2015
    model_id:                       GERICS-REMO2015
    forcing:                        N/A
    ...                             ...
    title:                          GERICS-REMO2015 model output prepared for...
    parent_experiment:              N/A
    modeling_realm:                 atmos
    realization:                    1
    cmor_version:                   2.9.1
    tracking_id:                    hdl:21.14103/e7ee14a3-6fb4-4f3e-8e10-fe4b...
#I need to slice the EURO-CORDEX domain to my study area with the following lat and lon

min_lon = 24.344
min_lat = 43.609
max_lon = 25.739
max_lat = 45.672

sliced_ds = ds.sel (rlat=slice(min_lat,max_lat), rlon=slice(min_lon,max_lon)) 

#this results in a dataset with
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                     (time: 1826, bnds: 2, rlat: 0, rlon: 0,vertices: 4)
```